# Program or app that displays virtual hands playing piano piece?

Tags: music, midi, learning

I currently use Synthesia to learn classical piano pieces. In Synthesia, as well as assigning left and right hand parts, you can also add finger hints to each key and create a visual record (in piano roll form) of exactly how you play a piece.

I was wondering if there is any Windows program or Android app that takes this a step further and displays a virtual pair of hands actually playing a piece. So, for example, you could input a midi file into this app/program, assign your own fingering to each note then watch the virtual pianist play the piece in the same way that you do.

Does anyone know if anything like this exists?

Answer (score 0):

It [looks](https://youtu.be/QJaA4NTpsug) like "[Flowkey](https://www.flowkey.com/)" has a split-screen display with video of hands on a keyboard above scrolling music notation. It doesn't look to me like it can import new content (in fact, makes access to some of their catalogue a paid feature). Looks like you can connect a keyboard via MIDI for detecting input, though.

That doesn't really do what you're looking for, a visualization of your personal fingering choices, but I'm not aware of

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like a useful app, but as you say, it's not exactly what I'm looking for, as I'd like to be able to import midi files.